# Populate query in array nested documents - mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My Output is in below image

[image]

and my populate query

```
Post.findOne({_id:req.query.id}).
   populate('user').
   populate('comment').
   exec(function(err,docs){
       if(err){
           console.log(err);
       }
           console.log(docs);
       res.send(docs);
   });
});
```

How do I get user object data in comments array?

Comment: Can you please try to include the actual code in your question instead of images because code in images can't be copied and pasted into an editor and compiled in order to reproduce the problem? Among many other reasons why it's not generally recommended to post images of code here on SO, images are large and hard to read on some mobile devices, they can't be searched and therefore aren't useful to future readers

Comment: please post your schema - the query looks ok, so the problem must be in the schema. ahh - I just noticed. Your query is working, but you have not found a way to populate your Post.comment.comments.user field. See below for answer.

Answer (score 0):

It used to be impossible with mongoose to populate fields of deeper populated objects directly in the query, but you could always use manual population by passing your resultdocs to the `Comment.populate(comments, options, cb)` method  (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate) inside your first callback.

With newer mongoose versions you should be able to do it directly using this syntax:

```
Post.
    find().
    populate({
        path: 'comment',
        populate: { 
            path: 'comments',
            populate: 'user' 
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Did this method solve your question or did it not work? I never tried this new syntax myself, but am interested whether it works